# Server Side Kendo Scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, scheduling, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I want to Use Kendo Scheduler in my MVC Application.
But in that the Problem is with Scheduled task fetching. Because that is not on Server Side.
I have also done Google, but still not getting any sugegstion on How to use **Server Side Kendo Grid**
Currently I am refereing Kendo Scheduler from:: [Kendo Scheduler Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/index.html)

But that is on Client Side(i.e. it reads all the data from database).

I want Server side Scheduler because of following reasons:

If Database is having Millions of Schedule (i.e. Pervious Date + Current Date + Next Few months) then in that case I want the information of just `Current Months/Week/Day` for that I need Server side Kendo Scheduler.

Comment: What kind of data access solution are you using? EntityFramework?

Comment: If you want to use Server Side Kendo, you'll need a license from Telerik. You can find a server side MVC scheduler component here:
http://www.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/scheduler

Personally, I feel the Dev Craft Complete is the best deal, but there are individual licenses for just Kendo available as well.

Answer (score 1):

Server side scheduler is easy. Client configuration:

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
   // highlightning just the parts important for server-side sourcing
   dataSource: {
     batch: true,
     transport: {
       read: {
         url: "/Services/kendo-scheduler/read",
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         type: "POST"
       },
       update: {
          url: "/Services/kendo-scheduler/update",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          type: "POST"
        },
        create: {
          url: "/Services/kendo-scheduler/create",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          type: "POST"
        },
        destroy: {
          url: "/Services/kendo-scheduler/destroy",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          type: "POST"
        },
        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
          var result = options;
          if (operation === "read") {
            var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
            var result = {
              start: scheduler.view().startDate(),
              end: scheduler.view().endDate()
            };

            return kendo.stringify(result);
          }
          return kendo.stringify(options);
        }
      },
      serverFiltering: true,
      schema: {
        data: "items",
        model: {
          id: "taskId",
          fields: {
            taskId: { from: "TaskID", type: "String" },
            title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
            start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
            end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
            startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
            endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
            description: { from: "Description" },
            recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID", type: "Number" },
            recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
            recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
            ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 1 },
            isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
          }
        }
      }       
    }
});
```

Server side (I'm using WCF but any rest API will do):

Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITaskService
{
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/read", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  [Description("Return list of all events")]
  KendoTaskCollectionResponse Read(DateRange range);
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/destroy", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  [Description("Delete an event")]
  KendoTaskCollectionResponse Destroy(KendoTaskCollectionRequest model);
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/create", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  [Description("Create an event")]
  KendoTaskCollectionResponse Create(KendoTaskCollectionRequest model);
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/update", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  [Description("Update an event")]
  KendoTaskCollectionResponse Update(KendoTaskCollectionRequest model);
}

[DataContract]
public class ErrorResponse : IErrorResponse
{
  [DataMember]
  public virtual string Error { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public virtual string ErrorUID { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public virtual bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class KendoTaskCollectionRequest
{
  [DataMember(Name="models")]
  public IList<KendoTask> Models { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class KendoTaskCollectionResponse : ErrorResponse, IClientResponse<KendoTask>
{
  public KendoTaskCollectionResponse()
  {
    Items = new List<KendoTask>();
  }

  public KendoTaskCollectionResponse(IList<KendoTask> list)
  {
    Items = new List<KendoTask>(list);
  }

  [DataMember(Name="items")]
  public IList<KendoTask> Items { get; set; }
}

public interface IClientResponse<T> : IErrorResponse
{
  IList<T> Items { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class KendoTask
{
  [DataMember]
  public string TaskID { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Title { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Description { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Start { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string StartTimezone { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string End { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string EndTimezone { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public int? RecurrenceID { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public int? OwnerID { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class DateRange
{
  [DataMember(Name = "start")]
  public string Start { get; set; }
  [DataMember(Name = "end")]
  public string End { get; set; }
}
```

Implementation of contract:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class TaskService : ITaskService
{
  protected T SafeExecute<T>(Func<T> action) where T : IErrorResponse, new()
  {
    try
    {
      return action.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      // publish the error somewhere - logs 
      var response = new T();
      // this is just for development, on prod 
      // you'd want to hide this error  
      response.Error = e.ToString();
      return response;
    }
  }

  public KendoTaskCollectionResponse Read(DateRange range)
  {
    return SafeExecute<KendoTaskCollectionResponse>(() =>
    {
      var start = DateTime.Parse(range.Start, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      var end = DateTime.Parse(range.End, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      // lookup to db based on start and end
      var appointments = ...;
      return new KendoTaskCollectionResponse(appointments);
    });
  }

  public KendoTaskCollectionResponse Destroy(KendoTaskCollectionRequest model)
  {
    return SafeExecute<KendoTaskCollectionResponse>(() =>
    {
      var result = new List<KendoTask>();
      if (model.Models != null)
      {
        foreach (var task in model.Models)
        {
          // delete from db here
          result.Add(task);
        }
      }
      return new KendoTaskCollectionResponse(result);
    });
  }

  public KendoTaskCollectionResponse Create(KendoTaskCollectionRequest model)
  {
    return SafeExecute<KendoTaskCollectionResponse>(() =>
    {
      var result = new List<KendoTask>();
      if (model.Models != null)
      {
        foreach (var task in model.Models)
        {
          // insert to db here, don't forget to set task.TaskID
          result.Add(task);
        }
      }
      return new KendoTaskCollectionResponse(result);
    });
  }

  public KendoTaskCollectionResponse Update(KendoTaskCollectionRequest model)
  {
    return SafeExecute<KendoTaskCollectionResponse>(() =>
    {
      var result = new List<KendoTask>();
      if (model.Models != null)
      {
        foreach (var task in model.Models)
        {
          // update db here
          result.Add(task);
        }
      }
      return new KendoTaskCollectionResponse(result);
    });
  }
}
```

Running the service (in Global.asax.cs):

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {  
  routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Services/kendo-scheduler", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(TaskService)));
}
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);    
}
```